# Angular 6 Multi Step Dynamic Forms - Saving dynamically added form fields and data

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I'm building a multi step form using angular 6 FormBuilder. Currently the routing structure is as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component:HomePageComponent,
  children: [

    {path: '', redirectTo: 'path', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'path', component: FormsContainerComponent , data: {channel:'path'}},
    { path: 'path2', component: FormsContainerComponent, data: {channel:'path2'}},
    { path: 'path3', component: FormsContainerComponent, data: {channel:'path3'}},
    { path: 'path4', component: FormsContainerComponent, data: {channel:'path4'}}
  ]
},
];
```

and I ran into a problem while implementing this i.e. when the user interacts on /path1 page and adds a dynamic form field and then moves on to next page (/path2) using the Next button and returns back to /path1 page then he was not able to see the dynamically added form fields as those are added only when the user clicks on add button. My generated form is similar to  the form seend here http://angular-multi-step-wizard.azurewebsites.net/#/personal, but a very complicated and nested one than that.

Solution I am looking of is how to save dynamically added form fields and pre-populate the user added inputs once he/she returns back to previous page.

Thanks for your help and support !

Comment: use a service to store the data in each step, and in ngOnInit create the form using the data of the service

Comment: Can you please reply to my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54570308/10358404

Answer (score 0):

I am building something very similar. You can use `NgRx` here, and save data to the store every time the user clicks Next or Previous.

However, with my project, there are some complex fields within each page that only mutate a very specific part of the Object placed in the `NgRx` store.

This led me to create a custom service based on the `BehaviourSubject` class. I `dispatch` data to the service which then adds it to the `BehaviourSubject` property of the service, and within each page i `subscribe` to the `BehaviourSubject` property of the service, and if the value(s) are not `null` I patch my `ReactiveForm` accordingly.

Comment: Any sample repo would be great !!

Comment: @Raj I don't have a sample repo but [this guide](https://www.technouz.com/4776/custom-angular-application-state-service-with-behavioursubject/) I wrote may help.